# Use Docker Compose offline by using local images and not pulling images

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to issue the docker-compose command to bring up all the dependent service containers that I have previously pulled down while inside the company network.  I am outside the company network so when I try to start my environment the first thing it does is try to call out to the company network and then fails with:

ERROR: Error while pulling image: Get http://myartifactory.service.dev:5000/v1/repositories/my_service/images: dial tcp 127.0.53.53:5000: getsockopt: connection refused

How can I force docker-compose to use the local images and not try to pull down the latest?

Comment: can you see the images on your docker host when you run `docker images`?

Comment: Yes the images are there.  Not even sure how to run a single image without it trying to connect to the network though.

Comment: Using image with digest in compose file without a tag is a way to prevent the image pull. When tags are used, docker tries to verify the freshness to see if there are changes.

Comment: That seems to be correct.  However upon issuing the command 'docker run e1779b099561' the first thing that happens is it tries to download gradle from the secure company network and then throws a connection refused exception.  Not sure it's possible to change that behaviour on the existing image.

Comment: I think if the image has a tag and not digest, we cannot modify the checking for freshness behavior at runtime.

Comment: Brilliant thanks @Screeni.  I was doing something silly and not using the digest, but the id.  I was able to get the digest by running `docker images --digests` and then using that in the docker-compose file to fix the problematic container.  If you want to post this as an answer I will accept it.  Thanks! :)

Comment: sadly my images do not have a digest as i loaded them from a tar-file

Answer (score 0):

You can force docker-compose to use local images by first running:

```
docker-compose pull --ignore-pull-failures
```

Comment: Just a warning: this may not work with later versions of docker-compose